# broadleaf admin framework - delete operation confirmation required

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Sometimes, on the admin, delete button is clicked by user by mistake. Specially, when working with collections, Instead of Edit button, sometimes user ends up clicking on delete button. Adding back the deleted entity becomes a hassle.

Is there a way to hook up a confirmation dialog before deleting any entity from the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, add a JQuery click handler to `$('.entity-form-actions .delete-button')`. In this clickhandler, show a popup and then return true or false to continue execution of the normal click handler.